# people breaching my queries

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I've been trying to make a transaction using queries; I've done that like so, first I check and execute a query to check if an user has enough balance, secondly I deduct his balance and process the transaction.

Problem with this is if you download a tool, or use a macro that can click like 200 times per second (I think) the signals are sent quicker than the query can handle therefore it will still think the user has enough balance which he then ends up not having and his balance will become negative.

**Here's the quick code**

```
var processTransaction = function(userid, cost){
    database.query('SELECT `balance` FROM `user` WHERE `id` = ' + database.pool.escape(userid), function(err, row){
        if(err){
            return;
        }

        if(!row.length){
            return;
        }

        var userBalance = row[0].balance;
        if(userBalance >= cost){
            /* User has enough, process */

            addBalance(userid, -cost); //deduct query
        }
    });
}
```

is there any mistake I'm making here, do I approach this differently?

**Query Function**

```
var query = function(sql, callback) {
  if (typeof callback === 'undefined') {
    callback = function() {};
  }
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if(err) return callback(err);
    connection.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
      if(err) return callback(err);
      connection.release();
      return callback(null, rows);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: in mysql you can use `select ... for update` to lock row

Comment: @IłyaBursov 'lock row' ?

Comment: yes, lock row to prevent update in another thread

Comment: You can also try to fit everything into one query, something like `UPDATE user SET balance=balance-x WHERE id=y AND balance>=x`.

Comment: @riv I currently have a lot of sections using queries in the same way, it'll take me a long while to change everything to fit in one query, sadly.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira huh?

Comment: @IłyaBursov I updated to query to have FOR UPDATE but still didn't change anything.

Comment: The `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` is in the transaction?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be sure that the database is in a *consistent state*. You can do this in several ways, the simplest of which:

- using `LOCK TABLE user WRITE` to prevent access to the user table (and UNLOCK TABLES as soon as you're done). If you click 200 times, no worry - the clicks will all be queued and won't be able to run concurrently.

This from [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html):

> The correct way to use LOCK TABLES and UNLOCK TABLES with
>   transactional tables, such as InnoDB tables, is to begin a transaction
>   with SET autocommit = 0 (not START TRANSACTION) followed by LOCK
>   TABLES, and to not call UNLOCK TABLES until you commit the transaction
>   explicitly. For example, if you need to write to table t1 and read
>   from table t2, you can do this:
>
> ```
> SET autocommit=0;
> LOCK TABLES t1 WRITE, t2 READ, ...;
> ... do something with tables t1 and t2 here ...
> COMMIT;
> UNLOCK TABLES;
> ```
>
> When you call LOCK TABLES, InnoDB internally takes its own table lock,
>   and MySQL takes its own table lock. InnoDB releases its internal table
>   lock at the next commit, but for MySQL to release its table lock, you
>   have to call UNLOCK TABLES. You should not have autocommit = 1,
>   because then InnoDB releases its internal table lock immediately after
>   the call of LOCK TABLES, and deadlocks can very easily happen. InnoDB
>   does not acquire the internal table lock at all if autocommit = 1, to
>   help old applications avoid unnecessary deadlocks.

Comment: When do I unlock the table, what if the query returns an error?

Comment: You still need to unlock. You can also wrap everything inside a SQL transaction, so that if an error occurs you can issue a ROLLBACK and it's as if nothing happened. Otherwise you COMMIT. Added the example from the MySQL manual.

Comment: `LOCK/UNLOCK TABLES` is not for use by InnoDB.  You are using InnoDB, aren't you!?!

Comment: @RickJames sorry, but how is LOCK/UNLOCK tables "not for use by InnoDB"? The manual seems to say the opposite. It's true that you *can* set things up so you needn't use LOCK/UNLOCK tables, but there are scenarios where you have little other choice.

Comment: @LSerni - OK, `LOCK TABLES` may work with InnoDB.  It was invented for MyISAM, where there is no transactional locking.  For InnoDB, it is a sledgehammer chasing a fly.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizing a "queuing" architecture would also allow for you to handle concurrent requests more readily. The concept is all the requests are pushed into a queue. There is a worker set to "poll" this queue, likely on a cron of some sort, to read from the queue and disburse work. When items are received by the worker, it will issue your update/create request more sequentially and prevent race conditions. With this type of behavior, you will need to be more equipped to handle asynchronous events.

Comment: while I think this idea is good, I want to mention that would make both BE and FE code more complicated since user still wants to see result of his/her action. and with this approach reaching that goal would become much harder

Comment: @skyboyer agreed, the tradeoff is handling asynchronous operations. Many queue techs, like redis, have operations baked in to view state of tasks.

Comment: "Don't queue it, just do it".  If the actions are quick, the overhead of enqueuing/dequeuing may exceed the action.  Instead, let's try to fix what is causing conflicts between connections.

Answer (score 0):

What about making `UPDATE` without `SELECT`?

```
UPDATE user_balance 
SET balance = balance - :value 
WHERE user_id = :user_id AND balance >= :value
```

I believe this approach and transactions themselves should help to avoid reaching negative balance.

[UPD] and for detecting if balance has been actually updated or not(because of invalid balance for sure) you can read amount of rows affected(depending on lib used it could be separated method or [result of `UPDATE`](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#getting-the-number-of-affected-rows) query)

Comment: Point here is, how do I send the user an update telling him his balance is invalid?

Comment: mysql provides your code with response "how much rows were affected". If there is 0 - then nothing has been updated(and what a reason? invalid balance for sure!).

Comment: or you may `SELECT` balance after `UPDATE` - not for creating error message only but also to ensure user sees 100% valid balance in their UI

Comment: If you do a `SELECT` afterwards, put it in a transaction with the `UPDATE`.